# How can I use the calendar button in element, vue.js?

Tags: datepicker, vue.js, element

About element,a Vue 2.0 based component library. 
I want to create a button of datepicker to convert it to Japanese calendar, WAREKI.

But there is only the type of input tag in official document.
So, how can I use the button type of datepicker?
Now I make datepicker and input tag for displaying Japanese calendar.
But I don't want to display just a button not datepicker.

```
      <el-date-picker class="date" v-model="value1" type="date" id="demo_date" v-if="display" @change="show_wareki">
  </el-date-picker>
  <input class="date" type="text" v-model="value2"  v-if="!display" @click="show_date">
```

For example:
[the button type of datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kbST.png)
[after click button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10uvW.png)

Comment: can you share its actual lib source link

Comment: http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker#datepicker

Comment: Thank you for comment.The above is a link